# check if a file starts with a shebang

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I try to grep files for the shebang (ex: `#!/bin/bash`)

the code looks like that

```
#!/bin/bash

pr_id=$1
files=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/os-autoinst/scripts/pulls/${pr_id}/files | jq -c '.[].filename')
#checker() {
for n in "$files"; do
    echo "$n"
    if [[ -f "$n" ]] && [[ $(head -1 $n | grep "^#!" > /dev/null) -eq 0 ]]; then
       echo "gonna test $n"
       if [[ $(sed -n '/\t/p' '$n' | wc -l) > 0 ]]; then
          echo "$n is using TAB"
          return 1
       fi
    return 0
fi
done
#}

#checker
```

however `$(head -1 $n | grep "^#!" > /dev/null) -eq 0` doesnt seem to work properly.
Actually i have strange behavior and i would like to understand why behaves like that, as this and many answers I have found on SO and they supposed work for others fail for me.

Other things i tried (all return 1 instead of 0

- `head -1 file | grep -F '^#!'`
- `head -1 file | grep -E '/^#!/'`

Comment: Regarding "`$(head -1 $n | grep "^#!" > /dev/null) -eq 0` doesnt seem to work properly. Actually i have strange behavior and i would like to understand why behaves like that". We can't explain a problem if you don't describe the problem. Saying "doesnt seem to work properly" and "i have strange behavior" tells us nothing about whatever the problem is you're having and so makes it far more difficult for us to help you with your request "i would like to understand why behaves like that".

Comment: No need for `head` or `grep` or `awk` at all -- the shell itself can do everything called for with only built-in functionality. `if IFS= read -r line1 <"$n" && [[ $line1 = "#!"* ]]; then`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - is it worth adding `-N2` on the off chance you hit a large file with no delimiter? Or is that just paranoia?

Comment: @PaulHodges, nothing wrong with some paranoia. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(...)` captures standard output, but you are explicitly discarding all output with `... > /dev/null`. All you really need is the *exit* status of `grep`, which doesn't require the use of `[[ ... ]]` at all.

```
if [[ -f "$n" ]] && head -1 "$n" | grep -q "^#!"; then
      ...
fi
```

Comment: clear enough and nice explaination. thanks

Comment: Test could save a pipe by using `awk 'NR==1{exit(!/^#!/)}END{exit(NR==0)}' "$n"`. In a way, I am a bit more concerned by the for loop on a string rather than an array `for n in "$files";`

Comment: @LéaGris `exit(!/^#!/)` doesn't exit awk immediately, it just jumps to the END section where `END{exit(NR==0)}` will cause the awk script to ignore the previous `exit()`s arg and always exit with status 0/success. You need something more like `awk 'NR==1{f=(/^#!/); exit} END{exit !f}'`

Comment: `awk 'NR==1{f=/^#!/}END{exit!f||NR==0}'` works and also handle case of empty file.

Comment: @LéaGris it'd handle empty files even without the `||NR==0` since `f` wouldn't be set if there was no input. I used `f=(/^#!/); exit` for efficiency btw just so awk wouldn't read the whole file.

Comment: Another way to save a pipe is `if [[ -f $n && $(head -c 2 -- "$n") == '#!' ]]; then`.  See the [comment by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862206/check-if-a-file-starts-with-a-shebang#comment137267362_77862206) for way to do it with pure Bash.